# Why do I post a Runnable into the main thread, but the Runnable was executed in a HandlerThread?

Tags: android, handler

This is the code with problems :

```
object MainThreadPoster : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

    fun postRunnableAtFixRate(runnable: Runnable, token: Any, delay: Long, period: Long) {
        postAtTime(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                runnable.run()
            }
        }, token, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delay)
    }

}
```

The MainThreadPoster is initialized with mainLooper, so the runnable function (in the postRunnableAtFixRate method) is expected to be executed in the main thread, but the problem is that the runnable function may be executed in a HandlerThread sometime.

This is the expected stack trace
[image: This is the expected stack trace]

This is the stack trace with problem
[image: This is the stack trace with problem]

Comment: and what is your problem actually? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: those screenshots don't show exception. What is the exception?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko there is no exception, but the runnable is not executed in the correct thread.

Comment: @pskink the problem is runnable is not executed in the correct thread, I want the runnable in postRunnableAtFixRate method executed in main thread, but it may executed in a HandlerThread sometimes

Comment: if you use `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` your `Runnable` will always be executed on the main, UI thread

Comment: @pskink yes, that's what I expect, but the stack trace show it's executed in a HandlerThread not main thread

Comment: `This is the stack trace with problem` this part of your question says that there is an exception.

Comment: `HandlerThread` is not the *other thread*, it is just a class, which maintains task for the handlers, and has nothing related to the thread on which the runnable will be run

Comment: so what `HandlerThread` are you using? i dont see it in your code

Comment: @pskink the HandlerThread is created by someone else. I have fix the bug, thanks for your help. I described the root case in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not invoke Message.recycle() in your code. In Android 4.4, if you invoke Message.recycle() multi time, the message will occur in the message pool multi times, and the message may exist in multi message queue at the same time。

this is the poc:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val mMainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private lateinit var mSubHandler: Handler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        btn_test.setOnClickListener {
            start()
        }

        val handlerThread = HandlerThread("sub thread")
        handlerThread.start()
        mSubHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
    }

    private fun start(){
        val message = Message()
        message.recycle()
        message.recycle()

        mMainHandler.postDelayed({
            if(Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()){
                throw Exception("should run in main thread")
            }

            start()
        }, 100)

        mSubHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1)
    }
}
```